# Как убрать отступ у card (Bootrap 4)

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap4

я начинающий веб-разработчик и не могу решить одну проблему. Когда я делал адаптивную версию сайта под Galaxy S5, столкнулся с тем что у card есть отступ справа, не знаю как его убрать.
Ставил margin на ноль, не помогает.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам стоит добавить Вашу разметку, чтобы можно было понять в чем проблема

Comment: Добавь код как мне тебе помочь?